# How BTrace's -classpath param support many jar files?

Tags: btrace

Sometimes we need to depend third part jar file when using BTrace.

Maybe i need import a.jar and b.jar to support BTrace script.How could i spell the `-classpath` param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem.

The `-classpath` param can be multi path of jar file.

In windows like `-classpath ./a.jar;./b.jar`

And in linux like `-classpath ./a.jar:./b.jar`